# sympy Expectation CoercionFailed("expected an integer, got %s" % a)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

I am calculating the expectation as follows:

```
e = Uniform('e', 0, 1)
l1 = dict(
        p1=[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]],
        p2=[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]],
        p3=[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]],
        p4=[[2, 1]]
    )
def type_pr(prediction_profile, action_profile):
    type_pr = dict(y=[],o=[])
    num_dev = {}
    for task, actions in action_profile.items():
        num_dev[task] = 0
        for position, action in actions.items():
            predictions = prediction_profile[position]
            num_predictions = len(predictions)
            for pred in predictions:
                num_match = 0
                if pred[0] == action[0]:
                    num_match += 1
                    if pred[1] == action[1]:
                        num_match += 1
                        break
            num_dev[task] += 2 - num_match
            position_pr = (1/int(num_predictions))*((1-e)**(int(num_match)))*((e/2)**(2-int(num_match)))            
            type_pr[task].append(position_pr)
    type_pr_y = np.prod(type_pr['y']) if num_dev['y'] <= 2 else 0
    type_pr_o = np.prod(type_pr['o']) if num_dev['o'] <= 2 else 0
    return type_pr_y, type_pr_o

pr_y_l1, pr_o_l1 = type_pr(l1, actions) 
E(pr_y_l1)
```

And I got the error:

```
File "/Users/joyouyou/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/sympy/stats/rv.py", line 770, in expectation
    return Expectation(expr, condition).doit(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/joyouyou/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/sympy/stats/symbolic_probability.py", line 275, in d
> oit
    result = pspace(expr).compute_expectation(expr, evaluate=for_rewrite)
  File "/Users/joyouyou/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/sympy/stats/crv.py", line 613, in compute_expectatio
> n
    return self.distribution.expectation(expr, x, evaluate=evaluate, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/joyouyou/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/sympy/stats/crv_types.py", line 3938, in expectation
    result = SingleContinuousDistribution.expectation(self, expr, var, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/joyouyou/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/sympy/stats/crv.py", line 375, in expectation
    p = poly(expr, var)
  File "/Users/joyouyou/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/sympy/polys/polytools.py", line 7215, in poly
    return _poly(expr, opt)
  File "/Users/joyouyou/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/sympy/polys/polytools.py", line 7181, in _poly
    product = product.mul(factor)
  File "/Users/joyouyou/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/sympy/polys/polytools.py", line 1473, in mul
    return f.mul_ground(g)
  File "/Users/joyouyou/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/sympy/polys/polytools.py", line 1290, in mul_ground
    result = f.rep.mul_ground(coeff)
  File "/Users/joyouyou/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/sympy/polys/polyclasses.py", line 423, in mul_ground
    return f.per(dmp_mul_ground(f.rep, f.dom.convert(c), f.lev, f.dom))
  File "/Users/joyouyou/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/sympy/polys/domains/domain.py", line 148, in convert
    return self.from_sympy(element)
  File "/Users/joyouyou/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/sympy/polys/domains/pythonintegerring.py", line 35, 
> in from_sympy
    raise CoercionFailed("expected an integer, got %s" % a)
sympy.polys.polyerrors.CoercionFailed: expected an integer, got 0.0370370370370370
```

I have multiple similar functions to integrate. Some do not give the error.
Appreciate any help.

The sympy version is 1.7.

I tried to use scipy instead of sympy, but it seems that I cannot use symbols in scipy.

Comment: Please add the SymPy version you used

Comment: Can you provide complete code? The code you show fails without a definition of `num_predictions`.